# Get current signers of a transaction and required signers

Tags: multi-sig, signer

I have 2 questions, given a transaction, is it possible to:

- get a list of the signers that already signed the transaction?
- get a list of needed signers?

  Returning a list like the following:

  - Signer A,
  - Signer B,
  - (Signer C, Signer D)

  So in this case signer A and B are strictly required, and then either C or D must sign as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a view of who signed a txn you can look into the raw XDR. You can drill into the object and view the signatures array.

It is not possible given a txn to get a list of signers needed prior to submitting to the network. If its really needed I can imagine you could write some function that takes a TXN and figures this out but it would require lookups at the very least on each account since youd have to determine things such as if the accounts have additional signers.